# How do I write a comma as a normal text in a CSV file?(the double quote method doesn't work)

Tags: python, csv

I'm using Python to output some data in a CSV file. It must absolutely be in a CSV file, I can't use anything else, that's what I'm ordered to do. The comma must be used as a separator, but sometimes the data contains a comma, so I put double quotes around the strings and it put them in one field. That's good so far, however what happens when the data also contains double quotes? There's no limit to what symbol can be contained in the data.

Comment: Are you using the `csv` module? It manages quoting for you. Nested quotes are doubled in the default (Excel compatible) configuration.

Comment: Will it do what I want it to do? To write a comma without separating the fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write out your data:

```
import csv

with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as outfh:
    writer = csv.writer(outfh)
    writer.writerow(['Data with , commas and nested " quotes', 'works just fine'])
```

You can adjust quoting behaviour, but the default (Excel compatible) setting will handle quoting of commas and nested quotes for you. Columns containing quotes or commas are quoted, with any embedded quotes doubled.

Demo:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(out)
>>> writer.writerow(['Data with , commas and nested " quotes', 'works just fine'])
>>> out.getvalue()
'"Data with , commas and nested "" quotes",works just fine\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

```
   5.  Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
       some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
       at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
       double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:

       "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
       zzz,yyy,xxx

   6.  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
       should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:

       "aaa","b CRLF
       bb","ccc" CRLF
       zzz,yyy,xxx


   7.  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
       appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote.  For example:

       "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
```